# Java multithreaded program getting stuck waiting

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm starting to code multithreaded programs in Java and I'm having problems with this particular program, which seems to get stuck in a waiting state indefinitely, even though it doesn't look like it should be able to.

In this program, there are threads which distribute numbers(tokens) across different containers: every thread has an array of containers from which to take the numbers from(it takes one number from each one), and an array of containers to put it in.

As you can see from the code, I make sure that before taking numbers, the Thread makes sure that every Container has a number ready to get, to avoid infinite waiting.

I tried the program with this structure: 4 threads and 4 containers, Thread 1 and 2 both take numbers from containers 1 and 2, and they both put them in container 3.
Thread 3 takes numbers from container 3 and puts them in container 4 and 1, and thread 4 takes numbers from container 4 and puts them in container 2.
The first two containers are initialized with one number, and the other two with no numbers, as you can see here:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Container[] c = new Container[4];
        ThreadT[] threads = new ThreadT[4];

        c[0] = new Container(1,1);
        c[1] = new Container(1,2);
        c[2] = new Container(0,3);
        c[3] = new Container(0,4);

        threads[0]= new ThreadT(0, 200, new Container[]{c[0],c[1]}, new Container[]{c[2]}, c);
        threads[1]= new ThreadT(100, 200, new Container[]{c[0],c[1]}, new Container[]{c[2]}, c);
        threads[2]= new ThreadT(500, 600, new Container[]{c[2]}, new Container[]{c[0], c[3]}, c);
        threads[3]= new ThreadT(200, 300, new Container[]{c[3]}, new Container[]{c[1]}, c);

        for(ThreadT t : threads) t.start();

        Thread.sleep(30000);

        for(ThreadT t : threads) t.interrupt();
    }
}
```

The program works for a while: one of the first two Threads gets to take numbers and transfer them in container 3 without a problem, but once the numbers are in container 3, the program stops for no apparent reason: Thread 3 should pass the `allTokensAvailable()`check in the `transferMessages()` function and get a number from the container, but it doesn't.

I tried moving some of the wait() conditions and trying different conditions altogether but with no success.
I print the status of all the containers every time they change for debugging.

```java
class Container{
    private int id;
    private Random r = new Random();
    private ArrayList<Integer> tokens = new ArrayList();

    public Container(int tokensToGenerate, int id){
        this.id = id;
        for(int i = 0; i < tokensToGenerate; i++){
            tokens.add(r.nextInt(10));
        }
    }

    public synchronized void putToken(int token){
        tokens.add(token);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized int getToken() throws InterruptedException {
        while(tokens.isEmpty()) wait();
        int result = tokens.get(0);
        tokens.remove(0);
        return result;
    }

    public void printStatus(){
        System.out.println("Container "+id+" has "+tokens.size()+" elements");
    }
    public synchronized boolean hasTokens(){
        return !tokens.isEmpty();
    }
}

class ThreadT extends Thread{
    private Container[] takeFrom;
    private Container[] sendTo;
    private Container[] allContainers;
    private ArrayList<Integer> tokensToSend = new ArrayList();
    private Random r = new Random();
    private int minWait;
    private int maxWait;

    public ThreadT(int min, int max, Container[] senders, Container[] receivers, Container[] all){
        takeFrom = senders;
        sendTo = receivers;
        allContainers = all;
        minWait = min;
        maxWait = max;
    }

    private boolean allTokensAvailable(){
        boolean result = true;
        for(Container c : takeFrom){
            if(!c.hasTokens()) result = false;
        }
        System.out.println("allTokensAvailable for "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+result);
        return result;
    }

    private void printAllStatus(){
        for(Container c : allContainers) c.printStatus();
    }

    private void transferMessages() throws InterruptedException{
        while(!allTokensAvailable()) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" waiting");
            wait();
        }

        for (Container c : takeFrom){
            tokensToSend.add(c.getToken());
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is receiving messages");
            printAllStatus();
        }
        sleep((r.nextInt(maxWait-minWait)+minWait));
        for(Container c : sendTo){
            for(int i : tokensToSend){
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is sending messages");
                c.putToken(i);
                printAllStatus();
            }
        }
        tokensToSend.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run(){
        try{
            while(true){
                transferMessages();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

In theory, Thread 3 should get a number from Container 3 and put a copy of that number in containers 1 and 4.

EDIT: I put a lot of print statements to figure out what's going on with the Threads, and it seems like there's an issue where threads are not getting to do the check even though I put `notifyAll()` instead of `notify`.
Here's the output from the program:

```
allTokensAvailable for Thread-2 false
allTokensAvailable for Thread-0 true
allTokensAvailable for Thread-1 true
allTokensAvailable for Thread-3 false
Thread-0 is receiving messages
Thread-3 waiting
Thread-2 waiting
Container 1 has 0 elements
Container 2 has 1 elements
Container 3 has 0 elements
Container 4 has 0 elements
Thread-0 is receiving messages
Container 1 has 0 elements
Container 2 has 0 elements
Container 3 has 0 elements
Container 4 has 0 elements
Thread-0 is sending messages
Container 1 has 0 elements
Container 2 has 0 elements
Container 3 has 1 elements
Container 4 has 0 elements
Thread-0 is sending messages
Container 1 has 0 elements
Container 2 has 0 elements
Container 3 has 2 elements
Container 4 has 0 elements
allTokensAvailable for Thread-0 false
Thread-0 waiting
```

Why is it that when container 3 receives an element Thread 3 doesn't even try to check? (there is no `allTokensAvailable for Thread-3 true/false`? It should at least check right?

Comment: You should remove `tokenAvailable` and use `!tokens.isEmpty()`instead. That way, you can be sure it's not a state change issue, and you could avoid the case where the value is set to true while the token has not been stored yet. I see potential synchronization issues in your code. Would it be a problem to put sync block around `tokens`usage? i.e remove the simultaneous put/get operations

Comment: I did remove the ```tokenAvailable``` boolean and used ```!tokens.isEmpty()```, as jhamon helpfully pointed out. I tried adding a ```notifyAll()``` in the ```while``` loop of the thread just to test if it was an indefinite waiting problem, but it still doesn't work, so it must be something else that's not related to waiting...

Comment: Where is the code that wakes up a thread that calls `wait` from `transferMessages`? Why is `transferMessages` marked `synchronized`? What race condition is that supposed to be avoiding? It looks like `transferMessages` will just get stuck in that `wait` and nothing ever wakes it up.

Comment: I thought it should wake up from the ```notifyAll()``` that's called every time a thread puts a token in a container. Am I doing it wrong?